# Заархивировать только нужные папки

Tags: linux, centos

Я пытаюсь создать tar архив такой командой

```
tar -cf file.tar --absolute-names /var/www/www-root/data/www/folder
```

В итоге получается tar архив с такой вложенностью папок:

```
- var
  - www
    - www-root
      - data
        - www
          - folder
```

Как сделать чтобы в архиве была только папка

```
- folder
```

и все что в ней находится?

Answer (score 2):

```
tar -cf file.tar -C /var/www/www-root/data/www/ folder
```